# Server is wrapping PHP output in HTML and escaping JSON -- what would do this?

Tags: php

I'm generating a JSON array for AJAX usage, but for some reason something is automatically surrounding my JSON response with HTML and encoding the characters like so:

```
<html><body><p>{&quot;this&quot;:&quot;that&quot;}</p></body></html>
```

Here is (literally all of) the PHP that is being echoed to produce the JSON:

```
echo json_encode(array('this' => 'that'));
```

I do not have the luxury of setting the header content type to be JSON (as this is a WordPress plugin that I cannot modify, and shouldn't need to). It works fine on my other servers. It's absolutely a server configuration issue either with Apache or PHP. Any ideas?

Closest I found was this, but I don't think it applies to me and I see no solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31844685/apache-reverse-proxy-wraps-json-response-in-html

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the

@header ("Content-Type: application/json");

It will not allow the proxy to modify the content, as it is not HTML

Comment: Like I said, I can't do that -- this is in a plugin. It works, but I can't do that. Thanks though!